# Approximation of an elliptic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation

I used some nice guesswork to get this formula
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}dx=\frac{ab\pi}{\left(a+b\right)\sin\left(\frac{a\pi}{a+b}\right)}$$
The comparision for some values of a and b are
$a=a,b=0, value=a, exact=a$
$a=1,b=5, value=5.236, exact= 5.2525$
$a=b, value=\frac{\pi.a}{2}, exact=\frac{\pi.a}{2} $
You can also check it gives consistent result. Am i right?

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g0w1nkeotm

Comment: This formula cannot be correct. The right-hand side is always 0 if $b = 0$, but the left-hand side is not. So, unless "nice approximation" is a set phrase which I am not aware of, your approximation is not so nice.

Comment: if u use $lim_{b \to 0}$ it will give desired result

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are facing elliptic integrals
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}dx=\sqrt{b^2}\, E\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)$$ Let us use $a=\lambda b$ and assume $b >0$ to get, as an exact result$$\frac I b= E\left(1-\lambda ^2\right)$$ that you want to compare with your rhs 
$$\frac{ \lambda \pi }{\lambda +1}\csc \left(\frac{  \lambda \pi}{\lambda +1}\right)$$ which seems to be "quite" good for $0 < \lambda < 2$ (look at the table below).

For the fun of it, plot both functions on the same graph.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 0.0 & 1.00000 & 1.00000 \\
 0.1 & 1.01372 & 1.01599 \\
 0.2 & 1.04720 & 1.05050 \\
 0.3 & 1.09329 & 1.09648 \\
 0.4 & 1.14807 & 1.15066 \\
 0.5 & 1.20920 & 1.21106 \\
 0.6 & 1.27516 & 1.27635 \\
 0.7 & 1.34494 & 1.34559 \\
 0.8 & 1.41780 & 1.41808 \\
 0.9 & 1.49322 & 1.49329 \\
 1.0 & 1.57080 & 1.57080 \\
 1.1 & 1.65021 & 1.65027 \\
 1.2 & 1.73122 & 1.73145 \\
 1.3 & 1.81362 & 1.81411 \\
 1.4 & 1.89724 & 1.89807 \\
 1.5 & 1.98196 & 1.98318 \\
 1.6 & 2.06765 & 2.06931 \\
 1.7 & 2.15422 & 2.15636 \\
 1.8 & 2.24158 & 2.24423 \\
 1.9 & 2.32966 & 2.33284 \\
 2.0 & 2.41840 & 2.42211
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Consider
$$f=E\left(1-\lambda ^2\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad g=\frac{ \lambda \pi }{\lambda +1}\csc \left(\frac{  \lambda \pi}{\lambda +1}\right)$$ Perform Taylor expansions around $\lambda=1$ and get
$$f=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}   (\lambda -1)+\frac{\pi}{32}   (\lambda
   -1)^2-\frac{\pi}{64}  (\lambda -1)^3+O\left((\lambda -1)^4\right)$$
$$g=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}   (\lambda -1)+\frac{\pi  \left(\pi
   ^2-8\right)}{64}  (\lambda -1)^2-\frac{\pi  \left(\pi ^2-8\right)}{128} 
   (\lambda -1)^3+O\left((\lambda -1)^4\right)$$ making
$$f-g=\frac{\pi  \left(10-\pi ^2\right)}{64}  (\lambda -1)^2-\frac{\pi  \left(10-\pi ^2\right)}{128}
    (\lambda -1)^3+O\left((\lambda -1)^4\right)$$ and, since $\pi^2 \approx 10$, this confirms, at least around $\lambda=1$ the quality of the approximation.

Comment: So was it a good approximation?

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary. Not too bad ! Good job and $+1$.

Comment: there is one more concern see this one <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236640/irrationality-from-infinite-rational-series> i agree with him do you?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g0w1nkeotm

It's a pretty good approximation